# Java Quick Sort

Tags: java, sorting

I am implementing quicksort in Java with the following requirements:

> Use recursion (in your quicksort implementation) down to a stopping case of a partition of size k or smaller. For these partitions, use an insertion sort to finish.

I'm confused as to how to implement this or even what it is asking. Here is what I have for the normal quicksort. How could I modify this to meet the requirements?

```
public static void quick_srt(int array[],int low, int n){
    int lo = low;
    int hi = n;
    if (lo >= n) {
      return;
    }

    int mid = array[(lo + hi) / 2];

    while (lo < hi) {
      while (lo<hi && array[lo] < mid) {
        lo++;
      }
      while (lo<hi && array[hi] > mid) {
        hi--;
      }

      if (lo < hi) {
        int T = array[lo];
        array[lo] = array[hi];
        array[hi] = T;
      }
    }

    if (hi < lo) {
      int T = hi;
      hi = lo;
      lo = T;
    }
    quick_srt(array, low, lo);
    quick_srt(array, lo == low ? lo+1 : lo, n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The partition size is `hi - lo`. So you could add something like,

```
int k = 7;
// ...
if (hi - lo < k) {
    insertion_srt(array, lo, hi);
    return;
}
```

before `int mid`. Implementing `insertion_srt(int[], int, int)` left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: So then after the mid variable there would be nothing since the insertion sort would take care of the sorting?

Comment: The rest of the method would do nothing, because the condition of the partiion being smaller than `k` triggers the insertion sort (and then `return`s).

Comment: Oh. I got it. Because the insertion sort would take place then the rest would have nothing to sort essentially.